# Stochastic differential equations form

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

Why do we write the stochastic differential equations in the following form 
$$dx(t)=f(x(t))dt+g(x(t))dW(t)$$
and we do not use:
$$\frac{dx(t)}{dt}=f(x(t))+g(x(t))\xi(t)$$
where the white noise $\xi(t)=\frac{dW(t)}{dt}$, i.e. $\xi(t)$ is the generalized derivative of the brownian motion $W(t)$. However, $W(t)$ is not differentiable anywhere.

I am confused, any clarification would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I've already seen SDEs written as
$$
\dot X(t) = f(X(t)) + g(X(t)) \, \dot W(t), \quad \quad (1)
$$
so the notation you propose. Remark that both this notation and the more classical
$$
\mathrm d X(t) = f(X(t)) \, \mathrm dt +  g(X(t)) \, \mathrm dW(t), \quad \quad (2)
$$
are actually only formally correct and are used as a common practical abbreviation. The rigorously correct way to write this would be employing the Itô integral, i.e.,
$$
X(t) = X_0 + \int_0^t f(X(s)) \, \mathrm ds +\int_0^t g(X(s)) \, \mathrm d W(s). \quad \quad (3)
$$
Once it's established that (3) is the rigorous (correct) way to write an SDE down, the choice of writing (1) or (2) is arbitrary.

Comment: If they are equivalent as you said, why do we use Ito formula instead of the chain rule.

Comment: Let $V=x^2/2$
then$ dV/dt=xf(x)+xg(x)\dot{w}$ for Eq(1)
and 
$dV=( xf(x)+g(x)^2 )dt +xg(x)dw$ for Eq(2)....
so they are different

Comment: It is just a way of writing things. You have to interpret $\dot W(t)$ as an Itô differential, too. I have a paper in my hands just now (there are several other examples in literature) https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/070694806, where the authors use the formal notation (1) meaning (3). Your $\xi(t)$ is just yet another way of writing $\dot W(t)$